# gstreamer 1.4.5 slow on pi

Tags: archlinux

I have arch installed on my pi and gstreamer1.45 installed. Any pipeline I try, playback is unbearably slow. I get maybe 1 frame every couple of seconds. Am I missing a driver or something? I dont have many packages installed, just enough to get i3 and gstreamer running.

I've tried simple pipes like this
`gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file://path/to/file.mp4`
And I've tried other variations similar to this
`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/path/to/video.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! omx264dec ! autovideoconvert ! autovideosink`

Thanks

Comment: whats your pipe?

Comment: Have you tried gstreamer0.10? I use it with mopidy with nothing to complain about. (mopidy installation procedures require this old version).